# How to get the auth value from my redux store and then use the value in my protected route?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-toolkit

Anytime I pass the auth state value from my redux store to my protected route component it immediately changes then flips back to the login page. Even when I set the state value of my app.js file and then pass it down to the protected route(HomePageWrapper) via props it doesn't still work. I logged the value to the console, it shows the value is true and it's suppose to work but it still doesn't. What might be the problem?

This is the app.js code

```
function App () {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.componentSlice.isAuth)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(updateAuth(true)); 
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <PositionedSnackbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<LoginWrapper />}>
            <Route index element={<Login />} />
            <Route path='register' element={<Register />} />
            <Route path='forgot-password' element={<ForgotPassword />} />
            <Route path='change-password/:id' element={<CreatePassword />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/homepage' element={<HomePageWrapper user={user} />}>
            <Route index element={<Homepage />} />
            <Route path='history' element={<History />} />
            <Route path='dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path='itemform' element={<ItemForm />} />
            <Route path='item' element={<Item />} />
            {window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches && (
              <Route path='listBar' element={<Cart />} />
            )}
            <Route path='history-details' element={<HistoryDetails />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}
export default App
```

Here is my protected route page

```
 const HomePageWrapper = ({user}) => {
  console.log(`this is the homepagewrapper user: ${user}`)
  return (
    !user ? 
      <Navigate replace to="/"/>
    
    : <div className='flex'>
      <div className=' w-fit bg-#FFFFFF'>
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
      <div className='flex-1 overflow-x-hidden'>
        <Outlet />
      </div>
      <div className='hidden md:inline w-fit'>
        <ListBar />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default HomePageWrapper
```

Update Auth slice code...

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
const initialState = {
    screen : "house",
    registerData: "",
    loginData:"",
    isAuth: false, 
    passwordParams: ""
};

export const componentSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'componentSlice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    changeSidebarScreen: (state, action) => {
      state.screen = action.payload; 
    },
    registerFormData:(state,{payload}) => {
      state.registerData = payload;
    },
    loginFormData:(state,{payload}) => {
      state.loginData = payload;
    },
     updateAuth:(state,action) => {
      state.isAuth = action.payload;
    },
    updatePasswordParams: (state,{payload}) => {
      state.passwordParams = payload; 
    }
  },
});

export const { changeSidebarScreen,registerFormData,loginFormData, updateAuth, updatePasswordParams } = componentSlice.actions;

export default componentSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Can you share the `updateAuth` code and the state slice/reducer code handling it?

Comment: @DrewReese, I just edited the code to include it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to find the issue there, but I see no overt issues in the redux code. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I've never used codesandbox, but let me see how I could go about it

Comment: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) is essentially a VSCode clone in the web. Just in case you have your code hosted in a github repo there's an option to even import directly from your repo.

Comment: I tried importing my public repo to codesandbox but I keep getting this error, "Could not find entry file: /index.html. You can specify one in package.json by defining a `main` property."